# how can i get data by using filter between array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i have Comment and ReplyComments data. I want to get only the data whose Comment data id and CommentId of ReplyComments match by using filter method. and i want to put data in arr2

answer it would be

```
         arr2 =
           [
            0: {id: 62, CommentId: 28}
            1: {id: 64, CommentId: 28}
            ]
```

this is data

```
            Comment = [
            0: {id: 28, content: "2", createdAt: "2021-03-07T14:07:19.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-07T14:07:19.000Z", UserId: 1, …}
            1: {id: 29, content: "3", createdAt: "2021-03-07T14:08:28.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-07T14:08:28.000Z", UserId: 1, …}
            2: {id: 30, content: "4", createdAt: "2021-03-07T14:25:15.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-03-07T14:25:15.000Z", UserId: 1, …}
            ]


            ReplyComments = [
            0: {id: 62, CommentId: 28}
            1: {id: 64, CommentId: 28}
            ]
```

i already tried but it doesn't work how can i fix my code??

this is my code

```
    let arr2 = []

    const arr = Comment.map((v) => {
        arr2 = ReplyComments.filter((value) => v.id === value.CommentId)
      
    })

    console.log("arr2:",arr2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost good. Try this :

```js
const arr2 = ReplyComments.filter(reply => Comment.find(comment => reply.CommentId === comment.id));

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use two `forEach`  loop.

```js
const comments = [
  {
    id: 28,
    content: "2",
    createdAt: "2021-03-07T14:07:19.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-03-07T14:07:19.000Z",
    UserId: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 29,
    content: "3",
    createdAt: "2021-03-07T14:08:28.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-03-07T14:08:28.000Z",
    UserId: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    content: "4",
    createdAt: "2021-03-07T14:25:15.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-03-07T14:25:15.000Z",
    UserId: 1,
  },
];

const replyComments = [
  { id: 62, CommentId: 28 },
  { id: 64, CommentId: 28 },
];

function matchingCommentData(comments, replycomments) {
  const result = [];
  comments.forEach(({ id }) => {
    replyComments.forEach((replyComment) => {
      if (id === replyComment.CommentId) {
        result.push(replyComment);
      }
    });
  });
  return result;
}
const result = matchingCommentData(comments, replyComments);
console.log(result);
```